# Struts2 recursive Wildcard Mappings for friendly url

Tags: recursion, struts2, wildcard, friendly-url

```
    <action name="en/articles/categories/*" class="it.cms.article.action.SearchArticleCustom">
        <param name="locale">en</param>
        <param name="categoryFriendlyUrl">{1}</param>
        <result name="success">/pages/article/search_article.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="en/articles/categories/*/*" class="it.cms.article.action.SearchArticleCustom">
        <param name="locale">en</param>
        <param name="categoryFriendlyUrl">{2}</param>
        <result name="success">/pages/article/search_article.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="en/articles/categories/*/*/*" class="it.cms.article.action.SearchArticleCustom">
        <param name="locale">en</param>
        <param name="categoryFriendlyUrl">{3}</param>
        <result name="success">/pages/article/search_article.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

So, I have a situation where categories can be nested with no limits.
The current struts-config file works pretty good for 3-level sub-categories.

Can I make this code sort of "recursive" to cover unlimited level of sub-categories?

Comment: You can try with to write regex that selects only last part of url and use `regex` `patternMatcher` or create a custom `patternMatcher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested, but I'd try something like:

```
<action name = "en/articles/categories**/*" 
       class = "it.cms.article.action.SearchArticleCustom">

    <param  name = "locale">en</param>
    <param  name = "categoryFriendlyUrl">{2}</param>

    <result name = "success">/pages/article/search_article.jsp</result>

</action>
```

From [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html):

> `**` : Matches zero or more characters including the slash ('/') character.